# Conditionals based on Gatling scenarios

Tags: scala, gatling

I'd like to know if conditionals (based on scenarios) are possible in Gatling.

I have a login post in Gatling 2.1.7 like so:

```
.exec(http("User login")
            .post("/api/user_login")
            .headers(Headers.headers_1))
```

Along with a couple scenarios:

```
val user1 = scenario("user1").exec(
    Action.login,
    Action.addDocument,
    Action.logout
)
val user2 = scenario("user2").exec(
    Action.login,
    Action.deleteDocument,
    Action.logout
)

setUp(
    user1.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
    user2.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Each user has separate login credentials (in the header), and is able to interact with the app in only certain ways.

So (in pseudo code) does Gatling support something like this?

```
.exec(http("User login")
            .post("/api/user_login")
            .doIf(scenario == "users1") {
                .headers(Headers.headers_1) // login info for user1
            }
            .doIf(scenario == "users2") {
                .headers(Headers.headers_2) // login info for user2
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the `scenarioName` from the `io.gatling.core.session.Session`:

```
http("User login")
    .post("/api/user_login")
    .headers(if(session.scenarioName.equals("user1")) Headers.headers_1 else Headers.headers_2) 
  session
```

But it could be an option for you, to use parameters for you `actions`:

```
def login(header: Map[String, String]) = {
  http("User login")
    .post("/api/user_login")
    .headers(header)
}
//...
Action.login(Headers.headers_1),
```